# Spring Boot Static Resources Duplicate Mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app that maps static content perfectly in normal. However, when I add some mappings like `/{username}/{info}`, that takes two string parameter, to a controller, it fails while loading the static content due to static content requests responded by the `/{username}/{info}` mapping.

For example, I have static files mapped as `/css/bootstrap.css`, etc. But the `/css/bootstrap.css` requests are sent to  `/{username}/{info}` mapping and they are not loaded by the way.

Is there any solution for this problem? How do I privilege the `/css/*` mapping? How I separate `/css/sth.css` mappings from `/{username}/{info}` mapping?

Comment: Which `Spring Boot` version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried ResourceHandlerRegistry before and It didnt work. However, I resolved the problem by creating one more folder inside /static folder. I added one more folder named as "static" to /resources/static folder and the final hierarchy was like that, /resources/static/static/css/*

By the way, I can use "/static/css/*" to map the static resources and It does not conflict with the "/{username}/{info}" mapping because my static url consisting of 3 string fields and the mapping only accept 2 string parameters.

Probably, there might be more elegant solution but there is no time to find out it for me. Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add ResourceHandlerRegistry entries for your CSS files, and store them within /resources:

https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot